# qgis2web: In which files are the zoom buttons?

Tags: zoom, geolocation, qgis2web, files

Can anyone help me out in which files (in an exported qgis2web project with OpenLayers3) the zoom buttons are specified? Or directly, the geolocation button? I do a project for school with qgis2web, and for the layout and data presentation i had to edit lots of javascript files after the export, so re-exporting the project is not an option, unfortunately. 
I did a seperate export, compared the files and managed to add the geolocation function after the export, it does work if i do hit the button. But the button has no mark, and its location in the window isn't lined up with the zoom in and out buttons.

[image]

Now i'm unable to find the right file in which i could line up the button better, or exchange it with another symbol/grafic.

Comment: Zoom in/Zoom out buttons are added by openlayers. You can customize them throw a CSS file. Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32111631/how-to-change-the-icon-of-zoom-contorls-in-openlayers-3

Comment: Thanks Zoltan! I found something independently of that stackoverflow thread, i could change the position of the button in directly in the main file index.html by adding a new line for the value for left alignement. Next step, design... ^^ thx again

Answer (score 1):

The position is set by some CSS in `index.html`:

```
.geolocate {
    top: 65px;
    left: .5em;
}
```

The icon, I'm afraid, is embedded into the geolocation plugin's CSS (https://github.com/jonataswalker/ol3-geocoder/blob/master/build/ol3-geocoder.css):

```
.ol3-geocoder-btn-search {
    position: absolute;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA8AAAAPCAYAAAA71pVKAAABPUlEQVQoU41SwXHCQAzUHh58eoUOIBWEDkI6oAToIKkg7iAuwakgpAIowXRACcnrzp6BzchjMx4wE/S6kW5XK60gvQghzJIkmVoqSZI9gJ9+/fINS5Cc1HX9QXIlIr/tpwcRyb33b7cIGnAIYQdg4pxbjcfj0nJ1Xc+Px+PGObdN03Q9RIAQwgpAnqbp7FKmjQGgJLlU1d2V7BjjRkQO3vvXIXarkyxVNbsCm2QR2Q0V7XOMMReRmfd+OQQubN6hYgs22ZtbnRcAtiRfLueqqmpJ8ovko6oeBq0KIWQA3gFkzrlmMafTaUEyI/mpqmbhVTRWWbRdbClPbeobQNES5KPRqOxs7DBn8K1DsAOKMZYApiTXqlrcDe4d0XN7jWeCfzt351tVle2iGalTcBd4gGDvvZ/fDe4RmCOFLe8Pr7mvEP2N9PQAAAAASUVORK5CYII=");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center; }
```

Comment: Many thanks Tom!

Actually, the value that worked to reposition the geolocator button was in the second part of the css code, 

`.o
l-touch .geolocate {
            top:  6.5px;
   left: 3.5em;
        }`

And yeah i gave up with the icon, i use an arrowed lagend in the title bar instead.... ^^